# Use php include or javascript ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, include

I am creating a application and I am trying to figure out what the best approach is for me to load in json files.

One approach I am considering is php include

```
var jsonFile = <?php echo include "jsonFile.json";?>;
var jsonFile_2 = <?php echo include "jsonFile2.json";?>;
 //and more possible includes
```

or is Ajax better?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "jsonFile.json",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function () {
        //more nested ajax calls 
   }
 });
```

Or maybe a mixture of the two?

There are 3 json files that would get loaded as of now, One of the files will grow over time and is unique per user, the second is a static file and the third is a large data file. The second and third file will be accessed by all users.

What is the best way to maintain efficiency and good performance with high user growth over time? Should I be worried about anything specific with php or javascript ajax when there are 1000, 10000, or 1000000 users accessing one file simultaneously? Is there a different approach that should be taken?

Thanks for all the tips/suggestions and different approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want it to act like. Each method is different. If you do an ajax call on $(document).ready, then the page will load first, then load the two files. If the files are massive then maybe you want to use AJAX, because then the whole page won't be slowed by that one call. If you want them there on pageload and only need them once, an include is fine. AJAX is only necesary when you want your calls to be asynchronous.

Comment: I have decided to go with a hybrid approach, I will be using php include for two of the files and use ajax for the user file which will grow over time.